# Interpretation: relative clause after a prepositional phrase

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, interpretation

Let's consider the following sentence:

> He loves these books on a shelf that his dad gave him.

I' m a bit confused about the meaning the sentence conveys. To my knowledge, I think this sentence can be interpreted as follows.

**Interpretation 1.**

He loves these books, and they are placed on a shelf. **These books** were given to him by his dad.

**Interpretation 2.**

He loves these book, and they are placed on a shelf. **The shelf** was given to him by his dad.

**Question.**

Which interpretation do you think makes more sense? Is there any general rule as to how we should **read relative clauses that appear after a prepositional phrase**, or is it just an ambiguous expression that needs more information to narrow down its meaning?

Any comment is absolutely appreciated!

**Update.**

Actually, I had found some sentences that, I think, give credits to both explanations before I posted the question, but I did not post them at the beginning because I thought it would be so technical that people might be distracted from my question. I decide to put them in the updated post because I am so confused by the structure of these kind of sentences, and they appear so often in math that I need to clarify them in order not to misunderstand.

These sentences come from John Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd edition. Please focus on the sentences with red marks.

(1) (pp. 158) This sentence justifies the interpretation 1.

Torus is not an image of a curve, so the relative clause is not used to modify 'the torus'. In fact, it is used to modify 'the sub manifold H'.

[image: Interpretation 1]

(2) (pp. 206) This sentence justifies the interpretation 2.

'Sense' cannot be continuous in math, so the relative clause must be used to modify 'the curve'.

[image: Interpretation 2]

Comment: We say _on a shelf_. I think most people would understand the clause to refer to the last-mentioned noun (the shelf).

Comment: @KateBunting Updated! Thanks

Comment: @KateBunting I actually found a textbook where the author uses relative clauses to modify the noun both before and in the prepositional phrase, respectively. I will update in the post. That's why I feel confused. I didn't put these sentences at the beginning because they are too technical and maybe distract people from my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fairly common example of ambiguity in English. [Here's](https://libguides.newcastle.edu.au/foundation-studies/feedback/ambiguous) an even more terse example:

> Example: There is a bird in a cage that can talk.
>
> Problem with the determiner: The placement of the word ‘that’ confuses the reader as we do not know if the bird or the cage can talk.
>
> Corrected: In the cage is a bird that can talk.

When facing such a sentence, you'd generally use context to infer the intended meaning - so it might be the shelf that was given, but would it make sense to mention that when the speaker only loves the *books* on that shelf and not the shelf itself?

Comment: So u are saying people would not mention the information about the shelf if they want to emphasize they only love the **books**?